# Calculated values in Repeating Table

Tags: xpath, infopath2010, repeat

[image]

I have this draft form, where I'm struggling to accomplish the following:
since I have `repeating table` and each row representing a month, I need the `Budget Remain` to recalcuated for each row (month) based on the following formula `Budget Remain = Budget -  Total (for all the previous months)` but must not affect the previous month's Budget Remain

i.e.:

```
Budget = 100  
jan : Cost + Penalties = 20 (Total) --> Budget Remain = 100 - 20 = 80
Feb : Cost + Penalties = 30 (Total) --> Budget Remain = 100 - (20 + 30) = 50
```

but when I tried to do that, I end up with each `budget remain` equals the `last budget remain calculated value`